# Strip all special characters

Tags: function, vbscript, asp-classic

Can anyone tell me that how to strip all special characters (<>,/\'%;()&+-*) in ASP (classic)?

This is what I have but it's not working.

```
Function RemoveBad(strTemp)

Dim regEx
Set regEx = New RegExp
regEx.IgnoreCase = True
regEx.Pattern = "[/\<|\>|\|\'|\%|\;|\(|\)|\&|\+|\-/g]"
RemoveBad = replace(strTemp,regEx.Pattern," ")

End Function
```

Comment: You will need to define *exactly* what you mean by "special characters".

Comment: And why do you need to strip them anyway?

Comment: To prevent cross-site scripting.

Answer (score 5):

To prevent XSS, all you need is this;

```
function RemoveBad(strTemp)
    RemoveBad = server.htmlencode(strTemp) 
end function
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`RegExp.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9z80300%28VS.84%29.aspx) method:

```
RemoveBad = regEx.Replace(strTemp, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a series of replcae statements in a function

```
Function RemoveBad(strTemp)  

strTemp = REPLACE( strTemp, Chr(1),  '')
strTemp = REPLACE( strTemp, Chr(2),  '')
strTemp = REPLACE( strTemp, Chr(3),  '')
strTemp = REPLACE( strTemp, Chr(4),  '')
strTemp = REPLACE( strTemp, Chr(5),  '')
strTemp = REPLACE( strTemp, Chr(6),  '')
strTemp = REPLACE( strTemp, Chr(7),  '')
strTemp = REPLACE( strTemp, Chr(8),  '')
strTemp = REPLACE( strTemp, Chr(9),  '')
strTemp = REPLACE( strTemp, Chr(10), '')
strTemp = REPLACE( strTemp, Chr(11), '')
strTemp = REPLACE( strTemp, Chr(12), '')
strTemp = REPLACE( strTemp, Chr(13), '')
strTemp = REPLACE( strTemp, Chr(14), '')
strTemp = REPLACE( strTemp, Chr(15), '')
strTemp = REPLACE( strTemp, Chr(16), '')
strTemp = REPLACE( strTemp, Chr(17), '')
strTemp = REPLACE( strTemp, Chr(18), '')
strTemp = REPLACE( strTemp, Chr(19), '')
strTemp = REPLACE( strTemp, Chr(20), '')
strTemp = REPLACE( strTemp, Chr(21), '')
strTemp = REPLACE( strTemp, Chr(22), '')
strTemp = REPLACE( strTemp, Chr(23), '')
strTemp = REPLACE( strTemp, Chr(24), '')
strTemp = REPLACE( strTemp, Chr(25), '')
strTemp = REPLACE( strTemp, Chr(26), '')
strTemp = REPLACE( strTemp, Chr(27), '')
strTemp = REPLACE( strTemp, Chr(28), '')
strTemp = REPLACE( strTemp, Chr(29), '')
strTemp = REPLACE( strTemp, Chr(30), '')
strTemp = REPLACE( strTemp, Chr(31), '')

' Add as many replace statements as you need

End Function
```

Comment: I wonder if that could be made a little more readable by sticking it inside a for loop?